# The execution of open when using O_CREAT

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, file-permissions, file-descriptor

I'm trying to understand some of the basics of os and I got stuck between flags and permissions.

If `open()` is used the follofing way
`int fd = open(path, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0000);`
in which conditions our file will have 0000 permissions and in which conditions our file will have 0666 conditions ?

At first I thought that if the file is already created, we will use it with 0000 permissions and if it's not created, will be created and used with 0666 permissions. I'm not really sure if i'm correct.

Comment: Nope.  The permissions argument is only used if the file is created.  If it already exists, the permissions on the file are unchanged and the mode in the call to [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

- If this open command is creating a new file then only mode=0000 is applicable here.
- If the file already exists then it doesn't matter what the value of mode is.

Here you are using mode=0000. If the file doesn't exist then it will assign "0000" permissions which means no one (user, group, other) has any read|write|execute permission.
Please use the proper mode value.

Comment: Note that it is perfectly permissible to use mode 0 when creating the file.  The file descriptor will be able to read and write to the file, but no other process will be able to open it for reading or writing unless it (ab)uses "appropriate privileges" (approximately "root privileges") — or changes the permissions on the file before opening it.

Comment: I never said the file descriptor can't use the file. Usually, we create files which are accessible by other users, group. That's why I mentioned above to use proper mode.

Comment: Hmmm; I always have `umask` set to at least `022` (so group and others cannot modify files I create, by default).  I've sometimes worked with `027` (no access for others, no write for group).  And I seldom want files created with execute permission — if I'm going to execute something, I'll set the execute bits, so there's some virtue in `033` or `037` — or even `133` or `137` (but then there are issues with created directories — you need execute permission on directories to be able to access the files (and directories, etc) within).

Comment: Also note that I didn't say that you said that the file descriptor can't be used. I just pointed out that the permissions on the created file do not affect the requested access mode (read only, write only, read/write) on the file descriptor. The permissions on a pre-existing file do affect the requested access mode, of course.

Comment: I had this type of question at an exam so it's not in use. Does the flag O_RDWR have any role there?